# correct use of java Commons BeanUtils?

Tags: java, reflection, jar, javabeans, introspection

Hi still learn some concepts in java. so sorry if this is a silly question

I Have a class in a jar. i am loading it to my class path dynamically using reflection. and then i am calling the classes constructor method like so :

```
        File jar = new File("C:\\Users\\JG\\Desktop\\testAlgorithm.jar");

        URL url = jar.toURI().toURL();            
        URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};

        ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);           
        Class classToLoad = Class.forName ("testAlgorithm.Stock", true, cl);

        Method[] m = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethods();
       Class[] cArg = new Class[1];            
        cArg[0] = String.class;

         Method method = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod("Stock",cArg);  

         Object result = method.invoke (instance, appl , start , end, 800, 30   );
```

so i am using method.invoke() to call the constructor, as a method. I want to use the class's setters ( eg stock.setDate() etc. . ) How do i do this ?

Have looked at other posts & someone has suggested the  Commons BeanUtils package ? 
[Best way of invoking getter by reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638590/best-way-of-invoking-getter-by-reflection)

I would like to know if  BeanUtils the  Is this the simplest why to do this, or if i am missing some obvious functionality provided by javas classloader and class object ?

Thank you guys !

Edit : More Info.   - add a bit of context.

The context is i have a PLay web server, & i am letting user uoload Jars to the server, for the server to use the classes in the uploaded jars.

Server will display the returned results of functions of classes in the uploads jars, after they have been run on the server, on a web page.

Comment: Why are you only using reflection? Doesn't it subclass something, or implement an interface, or...?

Comment: First of all, what's wrong with [`Class.getConstructor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor(java.lang.Class...))? Second, if you are only accessing getters and setters then BeanUtils is really overkill - see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15228381/2071828).

Comment: Hi , have edited post to include more information + some context. Thank you for getting back & providing some help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean somenthing like this:

```
try{
    Class<?> klass = Class.forName("[classname]");
    object = ([ObjectType]) klass.newInstance();

    String methodName = "setAddress"; //for example
    Method method = object.getClass().getMethod(methodName, java.lang.String.class);

    method.invoke(object, "[address]");
} catch(NoSuchMethodException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

** replace the [] with your values*

Answer (score 0):

Assuming java 7. Assuming `Stock` is the class and `testAlgorithm` the package (convention is only small letters and seldom '_').

Then it would go as:

```
Constructor c =  classToLoad.getContructor(String.class, int.class,
    boolean.class); // Any number of classes for constructor parameters.
Object obj = c.newInstance("", 3, true);
```